# Is there an open source AS lib can be used for mind-map-like application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there an open source AS lib can be used for mind-map-like application?

Answer (score 1):

Flare is good for data visualization. It's got AS3 classes for idea trees, pie charts, timelines and much more. I seems easy, but there's not a lot of tutorials on it. I hope this helps.

Website
http://flare.prefuse.org/

Demo
http://flare.prefuse.org/demo

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. flare is great for data presentation, but it doesn't seems have the capability to manipulate dynamically.